# How to unmangle exported symbols from C++ in dynamic libraries in Xcode on macOS

Tags: xcode, macos, symbols, dylib

I've been trying to develop a dynamic library in C++ that can be run-time loaded in an application. I finally got it working, but it's a little ugly. I have a function that takes a pointer to a C++ class as an argument, which looks like this:

```
bool registerGrindPlugin( Grind::PluginManager* mgr );
```

But of course it's being exported as:

```
_Z19registerGrindPluginPN5Grind13PluginManagerE
```

I tried a .c file with a simple function and it exported fine as "registerGrindPlugin", but of course I can't pass a C++ class as the argument that way.

So... my question is, is there a way to unmangle or alias the exported symbol so that I don't have to use a monstrosity like Z19registerGrindPluginPN5Grind13PluginManagerE in my dlsym call?

I did see something about -alias_list as a linker option, but I haven't quite figured out how to use it in Xcode. If that is the solution, can somebody provide some more details on how to use this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, plugin interfaces are defined with c-naming and calling conventions. Name mangling is potentially compiler dependent (non standard).

So the easiest solution is to define some interface function and declare that as `extern "C"`:

```
extern "C"  {
    bool registerGrindPlugin( Grind::PluginManager* mgr );
}
```

You may have to replace the Grid::PluginManager with a void* type and an internal cast. This has to be a simple structure, rather than a class with virtual functions.

If you do insist on dealing with mangled names you can take a look at the source code of 'c++filt' which is a gnu utility that is also available on OS X.

Comment: That was actually my first thought, as that's how I always did it in Windows. I tried extern "C" before but the compiler complained about the "C" for some reason, so I thought that might not be supported. However, I just tried again and it worked. Not sure what I did wrong the first time, but it's working great now, and I don't need to cast from void*. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

**The way you're trying to do it isn't going to work over the long haul.**

You can't count on any particular C++ mangling/demangling algorithm. Different compilers - and even different versions of the same compiler - have used different ones. So you could do this, and switch to a new version of Xcode, and be left in a bad situation.

Also, C++ suffers from the [Fragile Binary Interface Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragile_binary_interface_problem). To avoid that, all operations on the internals of a Grind::PluginManager instance, from creation to member access to deletion, need to happen in the same dynamic library.

Solving these problems is some of the rationale behind Objective C's messaging system, and the Windows OLE system.

**The C++ solution is to use a wrapper system.**

First, you need to define an opaque pointer type to stand in for Grind::PluginManager*. The C-language Cocoa bindings do this a lot.

```
typedef void* MyGrindPlugInManagerOpaqueHandle;
```

Second, for each operation you want to do on a Grind::PluginManager from outside the dynamic library, you need to use `extern "C"` to define a function with non-mangled C binding, and that takes one of those opaque pointers as an argument. For instance:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

void foo_wrapper(MyGrindPlugInManagerOpaqueHandle *bar);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

Third, the implementation in a C++ file will look something like this:

```
void foo_wrapper(MyGrindPlugInManagerOpaqueHandle *bar)
{
    Grind::PluginManager* baz = (Grind::PluginManager*)bar;
    baz->foo();
}
```

Comment: Not sure I follow all of that. PluginManager is not created or deleted in a dynamic library, it's created in the application and passed to the dynamic library, so that the library can register itself as a handler for certain things, such as image serialization. The PluginManager interface is very simple and is not expected to change. What would be the purpose of using an opaque pointer type rather than the actual pointer type, if I'm just going to cast to the actual pointer type within the function?

Comment: Read the Wikipedia article about the fragile binary interface problem. Basically, C++ objects are really just C structs with "syntactical sugar" to make them look fancy. A change in the class interface, or compiler version, or maybe even compiler settings, can rearrange the offsets of the items within the struct; C++ hides that from you. If one executable with one set of assumptions about member offsets trades pointers with a different executable with a different set of assumptions, they will each think the same member is in a different memory location, leading to data corruption or crashes.

Comment: Say, for instance, Grind::PluginManager has two methods: foo() and bar(). You use XCode 3.2 to compile your program, and when it builds the class vtable (which is effectively a C struct containing function pointers), it puts the function pointer for foo() first, and then bar(). But you use XCode 3.3 to compile your shared library, and it builds its vtable with bar() first, and then foo(). Then you make an object in the app, and pass a pointer to it to the shared library, and the shared library calls what it *thinks* is foo()... but what gets executed is really bar(), and your program crashes.

Comment: Thanks, I understand that. But that will be the case regardless of what type of pointer I use in the function declaration, as casting a void to a Grind::PluginManager is not going to have any effect on the structure of the underlying object, right? In any case, this is all meant to be compiled under the same environment; the dynamic libraries are mainly meant to be a way to save development time by not having to relink the entire massive application when working on these components. They will mostly be converted to static libraries for production. Something to keep in mind, though. Thanks.

Comment: @Gerald: You're right, pointer casts won't save you from a fragile binary interface. In a situation like you describe, where you can guarantee all the executables will be built with the same compiler and settings, you should be okay.

Answer (score 1):

You can set linker flags in XCode by selecting the target you're trying to build in the left-hand pane of the project window and clicking the "info" button. In the "build" tab, there's a whole section of linker settings, including one called "Other Linker Flags"; that should let you specify whatever linker options you want to try.